# Error trying use mercury wysiwyg editor in rails 3.1 app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a working rails 3.1 application that uses the mercury wysiwyg editor, however I can't get it working when pushing to heroku (cedar stack).  The application runs until attempting to edit a page, when the error is as follows:

ActionView::Template::Error (mercury.css isn't precompiled)

Note that I have precompiled the asset pipeline for production deployment, the rest of the app runs as expected.

Appreciate insight from anyone else that has managed to work through the problem!

Comment: Assets should compile once the code is on Heroku.  You do not need compiled assets in your repo.  Can you browse your assets manually?

Comment: the standard assets were compiling correctly, the problem was solved below - thanks for taking the time to think about it though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally figured it out....

In the file `config/environments/production.rb` add this in the `YourAppName::Application.configure do` block...

`config.assets.precompile += %w( mercury.js mercury.css mercury_overrides.css )`

There is a commented out section for `config.assets.precompile` that describes it.

Basically, `mercury-rails` isn't adding the js/css to the asset list for precompile.

I filed [issue #73](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/issues/73) for mercury about this.

Comment: worked great, thanks for the help, made sense, I should have read the fine print